# Does Swift closure retain captured variables?

Tags: swift

I discovered Swift closures are not retaining the captured variables unlike my expectation.

```
class AAA {
}
var a1  =   AAA() as AAA?                  // expects RC == 1
var a2  =   { ()->AAA? in return a1 }      // expects RC == 2, retained by `Optional<AAA>`
a1      =   nil                            // expects RC == 1
a2()                                       // prints nil, ????
```

I am very confused with this because I have been believed the captured variables will be retained by default. But, if I capture it explicitly using capturing list, it is being retains.

```
class AAA {
}
var a1  =   AAA() as AAA?
var a2  =   { [a1]()->AAA? in return a1 }
a1      =   nil
a2() // prints {AAA}, alive as expected.
```

I re-read the Swift manual, but I couldn't find related description. Capturing list is used to set `unowned` explicitly, and I am still confused.
What is correct behavior and why does this happen?

Answer (score 5):

Yes that's documented in [Capturing Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_163):

> Swift determines what should be captured by reference and what should be copied by value. You don’t need to annotate amount or runningTotal to say that they can be used within the nested incrementor function. Swift also handles all memory management involved in disposing of runningTotal when it is no longer needed by the incrementor function.

The rule is: if you reference a captured variable without modifying it, it is captured by value. If instead you modify it, it is captured by reference. Of course unless you explicitly override that by defining a capturing list.

**Addendum** The above statements appears to be incorrect. Captures are made by reference regardless of whether they are modified or not inside the closure. Read @newacct comment.

Comment: Not true. For example, `func test() { var x = 42; let f = { println(x) }; x = 43; f() }; test()` prints `43`, which means the closure captures the variable by reference, even though it references the variable without modifying it.

Comment: Thanks @newacct. Although not explicitly saying what I wrote, the documentation made me think it worked that way.

Comment: Is there a way to force the compiler to capture by reference?  I have a case where I have two closures each trying to access a shared value.  One closure modifies the captured value and the other only reads it.  However, the one that reads it is getting a copy.  I need to force it to capture by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't make sense @newacct. The variable x is actually modified outside the block. Swift is smart enough to find out whether you modify a variable inside or outside the closure.

As the document says:

> As an optimization, Swift may instead capture and store a copy of a value if that value is not mutated by or outside a closure.

As to the question post by @Eonil, in the first snippet, you have a strong reference to `Optional<AAA>` in closure. However when you set a1 to nil, what you actually do is removing the value of type AAA which is wrapped inside the optional.

When you call closure `a2`, you return the same optional with no value inside, which is exactly a `nil` means. So, holding a strong reference means your closure shares the same optional value as the `a1`. It doesn't means this optional can't be set to nil.

In your second code snippet, you captured `a1` within the capture list. This means you copy the `a1` and the value `a1` inside the closure has nothing to do with the value `a1` outside the closure. So even if you set a1 to nil, it doesn't affect what you get from the closure.

My English is not good and I hope I expressed my opinion clearly. Or you can read [this article](http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/26/swift-capturing-references-in-closures/), I believe it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I posted same question on Apple Developer Forum, and there was [a discussion](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1068362#1068362). Though people are not talking about reference counting a lot, but I got some ideas. Here's my conclusion:

- A value is always copied when it is bound to a new (explicit) name. Regardless of `var` or `let`.
- *Copied* in reference types means RC+1. Because it's copying of strong pointer like C++ `shared_ptr<T>`.
- Closing (closures capturing) does not change anything because there's no new name. It's same as you use them in same stack. This is what *by-reference* means. Nothing related to RC, and does not change RC because it's something like references in C++.
- Capturing list is an explicit (`let`) name. So it causes copying and it makes RC+1.
- When closure is returned from a function, it may be bound to a name. If it did, RC+1 because of new binding to a name.
- RC-1 when a value (so a strong pointer) unbound from its name.
- Implicit reference to `self` is the only exception which makes implicit name binding.

And there're many optimisations without breaking these rules, anyway those are just implementation details.